# Hiding/Displaying Label based on Drop-down selection value

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to display the bottom Label based on the selection made in the 1st (2nd & 3rd Selection); I tried playing around with Visible, but i can't seem to make progress. Any input would be appreciated.

```
 <tr>
            <td align="left" style="font-size:medium; font-weight:normal;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList12" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Enter Your Selection</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes - Due Date in 3 Days</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Yes - Due Date in 14 Days</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="font-size:medium; font-weight:normal;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="font-size:medium; font-weight:normal;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" 
                    Text="Fast Track Reason"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: this is not winforms

Answer (score 0):

I would put the bottom label in an update panel

Comment: Thanks Duston, I figured it out! Two separate panels work more beautifully. (noob delight! :P)